# How does OpenAI Whisper's medium.en, large and whisper-large-v2 compare in terms of word error rate?

Tags: speech-to-text

I want to use OpenAI's [Whisper](https://github.com/openai/whisper) to transcribe some speech files in English. I only care about minimize the word error rate. How do  `medium.en`, `large` and [whisper-large-v2](https://huggingface.co/openai/whisper-large-v2) compare in terms of  word error rate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information can be found in Table 9 of the [Whisper paper](https://cdn.openai.com/papers/whisper.pdf). Here is the table, which shows English transcription WER of the different models for different datasets, using beam search with temperature fallback:

[image]